# Htaccess 301 redirect index.html also redirecting addon domain issue

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have this issue that I can't figure out how to fix:
I am trying to redirect an html site to a wordpress site.
The domain I am trying to redirect as a primary domain which has an HTML site on it obviously with an index.html as the main page.
Now - there are 2 more sites on the same host which use addon domains and sitting in 2 directories:
**example.com** and **example2.com** (they are both wordpress sites)

I created an htaccess file, pretty simple and put many lines of redirecting html pages of the primary domain to another domain like so:

```
Redirect 301 /somepage.html http://www.newdomain.com
Redirect 301 /anotherpage.html http://www.newdomain.com
```

etc, etc..
at this point all the .html pages were redirecting fine.

Now - the issue is:
I also wanted to point the main page (index.html) to another domain (ww.newdomain.com) so I put this line too (same as I did for other html pages):

```
Redirect 301 /index.html http://www.newdomain.com
```

it seemed fine to me but what happened was that it redirects the index.html to the new domain but also redirected the 2 wordpress sites which are sitting in a different directory that I mentioned earlier...

I dont knw why did it happen but I can assum that redirecting the first page that the browser meet redirecting everything on the main root including addon domains.

does anyone have a solution to that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try changing (which I think you have a typo, I'm guessing it's not the same as the 2nd redirect in the first part):

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.newdomain.com
```

to:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ http://www.newdomain.com
```

EDIT: Since there appears to be more than one domain with the same document root try:

```
RewriteEngine On

# for redirecting "/"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain.com
RewirteRule ^$ http://www.newdomain.com/ [R=301,L]

# for redirecting "/somepage.html"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain2.com
RewriteRule ^somapage.html$ http://www.newdomain2.com/ [R=301,L]
```

etc.

Comment: Hi @Jon Lin
First of all, you right, in the second row I meant:  
index.html and not somepage.html  
I tried what you suggested here and unfortunately it is still redirecting the directories with the addon domain.
The question is: is there a way of ignoring the addon domains and refer only to the primary domain?
Thanks A lot!

Comment: @gilhamer Not sure what you mean by this: "redirecting the directories with the addon domain. The question is: is there a way of ignoring the addon domains and refer only to the primary domain?" What is the "addon" domain? There are others besides "newdomain.com"? Which one is the primary domain then?

Comment: what I am trying to say is that there are html files in the root folder that belong to the primary domain. in the root there are 2 directories which contains 2 different sites with different domains (totally fifferent wordpress website)  when I put the code you posted to basically redirect the index.html to a new domain it also redirects those 2 sites to that new domain.  I am only trying to redirect the HTML site to the new domain and not those 2 wordpress sites but when I type the domain of one of those 2 sites I get a redirection of the primary HTML site.

Comment: Thanks. tried that too but it gives my 500 internal server error. I will try to contact the host to see if they can change something on their end. I appeciate your effort! thanks